# What does subclassing do?

Tags: disgaea-5

So I've been playing Disgaea 5 for quite a bit and got a handle on most of the plethora of mechanics in the game but there is one that has still got me baffled as to what it does, subclasses.

What I do know thanks to reading walkthroughs is that you should subclass your unique characters as soon as you get them and leave your generic characters the alone until they max their subclass out then you can switch them out. I also know that you need subclasses to unlock new characters through the recruiter and provide small stat boosts to new characters created with the upgraded class.

So my question besides the minor stat boost and need for unlocking new characters what exactly does leveling subclasses do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclassing in Disgaea 5 allows you to level up other classes as a character without actually being that class. You could have a Magic Knight subclass as a Fighter to level them up while still being a Magic Knight. You can also learn Evilities from the class you are subclassing as, including the unique Evilities for each class. Another benefit to doing this (especially with an OP unit) is that you can unlock higher ranks of other classes that you don't like playing as without actually having to play as them.

This *will* prevent you from leveling your Magic Knight up as a Magic Knight during that time, though.

Subclassing is mainly for endgame power-leveling, as to max out a character, you'll need to have maxed out all class proficiencies. This is due to the fact that every maxed class will raise your stat caps, up to roughly 20m a stat once all classes have been maxed by a specific character.

Comment: When you say level up other classes you mean just rank of the subclass correct? Does the character learn skills from the subclass as well?

Comment: @Ramirez, yes that's what I meant. They cannot learn the skills of the classes they subclass as. To learn non-class skills, you need to put units in the Skill Squad.

Comment: Okay last little question since you mentioned endgame power leveling is there a stat boost that comes with leveling up different subclasses that makes power leveling easier?

Comment: @Ramirez, the only way to maximize your stats is to have maxed out all classes for a specific unit. This will raise their stat caps when you reincarnate that unit. It's a grind, for sure. It's been a while since I played D5, but I believe that once you've maxed all classes, your base stats will be capped around 20m. [This thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835980-disgaea-5-alliance-of-vengeance/72665346) seems to support this.

Comment: Oh okay that makes a lot of sense now, I'm still quite a way away from that kind of stat grinding but I am preparing myself for long haul of a grind to get there. Thanks Vemonus!

Comment: @Ramirez, it took me a solid month of grinding for the platinum, about 150-160 hours. Once you get to the designated grinding maps, you will literally jump from 1-9999 in about 15 seconds and just be constantly reincarnating over and over. Most of your time will be spent in the Chara World, slowly raising your stat multipliers higher and higher.